# AngularJS won't reload from file system in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I'm running Chrome, Version 46.0.2490.71 m, on Windows 8.1 and trying to test out an AngularJS app from the local file system.  Specifically, I'm trying to set up ['Step 3' from the official AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03).  I've pulled out the individual files (and removed the CSS) and will list them below.
The first time that I open index2.html in the browser it works fine.

If I then refresh the page (possibly 2 or 3 times - just keep refreshing until the problem appears :) ) then I get an exception from Angular because it can't find the controller. Specifically it says "Error: [$injector:nomad]Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it....".

If I close Chrome completely and then start it again the page is fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?  (And, more importantly, how to fix it?)

```js
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name':'F', 'snippet':'F2'},
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  $scope.f = 'f!';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"> -->
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that the first time the browser starts it needs to load everything from scratch and thus everything is getting loaded in the right order.  On refresh it might have some of the files cached (specifically the AngularJS file) and thus maybe the order in which my controllers.js file (the top file, above) changes?  Maybe?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this problem doesn't seem to happen when you run it from a web server.  So I guess that one work-around is to just run Node.js locally or something :/

Comment: can't run anything with ajax from file system, start the node server and load page from there

Comment: Where is the ajax being used here?  
The controller just defines a static array and attaches it to the $scope, which Angular then uses in the view.

Comment: may not be yet using ajax but how hard is it to turn on the node server and run from there?

Comment: I'm considering using this to teach a programming fundamentals class whose students who are still really new to programming & web design.  Running node isn't rocket science, and neither is Angular, and the core JS language, and HTML, and CSS, and having an editor that isn't part of an IDE.  But put them all together and it's a steep learning curve to handle all at once, so I'm trying to pare down what they need to deal with.

Comment: Also - regardless of the available workaround it's a bizzare and confusing bug.  So if a student did try to run it from the f/s and it didn't work it'll just be one more obstacle they'll have to overcome.

Comment: in that case create front end demo on working server perhaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93209/discussion-between-mikethetall-and-charlietfl).